# Одновременное выполнение участка кода на Си (проверка статуса Caps Lock)

Tags: linux, c

Есть некая игра реализованная в `TUI` интерфейсе, и в ней требуется ввести данные, думаю многие видели что при вводе пароля на некоторых веб-сайтах при включенном `Caps lock(e)` появляется надпись `Caps Lock включен` чтобы обратить внимание пользователя на это, если его отключить, то надпись пропадет. Так вот хотелось бы так же это реализовать только в моей игре. Как я понимаю это нужно делать асинхронно, не прерывая основной цикл программы (вопрос именно в том, какие системные вызовы для этого использовать). Последовательность программы и объяснения:

```
while (1)
{
// рисуется графика, окна и т.д
// программа встала и ожидает ввода от пользователя, тем временем пользователь может включить
// или выключить Caps Lock и данная информация должна мгновенно отобразиться на экране игры

// я могу создать буфер в котором будет информация о состоянии Caps Lock пользователя
// думаю что это будет утилита xset, а точнее башевский сценарий с красивым выводом
// xset -q | grep "Caps Lock" | awk '{print $2,$3,$4}'
// программа вызовет этот скрипт и запишет данные в буфер о состоянии Caps Lock пользователя
// затем хотелось бы вывести содержимое буфера на экран пользователя, но вот как делать
// это одновременно? если программа встала и ожидает ввода от пользователя, какие системные
// вызовы можно использовать чтобы участок кода работал одновременно
}
```

Вот примерная реализация задуманного / упрощенный пример:

```
int main(void)
{
    pid_t child;
    int pfd[2], n;
    char buffer[1024], c;
    pipe(pfd);

    while (1) {
        switch (child = fork()) {
            case -1:
                exit(1);
            case 0:
                dup2(pfd[1], 1);
                execl("caps_info.sh", "caps_info.sh", NULL);
            default:
                wait(NULL);
                if ((n = read(pfd[0], buffer, sizeof(buffer))) > 0) {
                    buffer[n] = '\0';
                }
        }

        printf("%s", buffer); /* Caps Lock: off */
        c = getchar();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Но минус этого примера в том, что мы не получаем свежую информацию о `Caps Lock(е)`. Ибо информация на экране игры обновится только после ввода символа. А это не то что нужно. Информация о статусе должна обновляться на экране терминала сразу же при нажатии на кнопку `Caps Lock`, но в тоже время, программа не перестает ожидать ввода от пользователя. Как этого добиться? Куда копать?

Comment: Смутно помню программирование X-window, но мне кажется, что когда мы читаем любой keysym, то в том же сообщении есть состояние всех модификаторов (если не ошибаюсь, то состояние CapsLock это один из них)

Comment: AFAIK средствами терминала запросить положение Caps'а в общем случае нельзя... можно узнать, что в X'ах, можно узнать, что на виртуальной консоли (см. `KDGKBLED` в `man 2 ioctl_console`), но что в конкретном псевдотерминале — нет...

Comment: понял, что вопрос не об этом... ожидать ввода из одного или более дескрипторов можно с помощью вызовов `poll()`/`select()`... но с потоками `stdio` это будет плохо согласоваться, так что читать нужно или низкоуровневыми средствами или библиотеками, поддерживающими неблокирующий ввод (`readline` или `curses`)... ЗЫ: `Caps Lock` в `xset` на самом деле показывает, горит ли соответствующая лампочка, а не включён ли капс на самом деле...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, спасибо за информацию